# Issues with JSVC and Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, jsvc

I'm trying to run tomcat 7 with jsvc, but am receiving an error even though I believe my classpath is correct.

I'm starting it as follows:

```
# export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_07
# export CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat7
# ./bin/jsvc -cp ./bin/bootstrap.jar:./bin/commons-daemon.jar -outfile logs/catalina.out -errfile /var/tmp/catalina.err org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
```

However, I'm receiving the following error:

```
# cat /var/tmp/catalina.err
Cannot find daemon loader org/apache/commons/daemon/support/DaemonLoader
Service exit with a return value of 1
```

I'd appreciate any assistance you can offer.

Cheers,
Toki

Answer (score 0):

It seems like javavms_conf is not in the correct path, verify where is it.
Usually /usr/local/bin/javavms check for /usr/local/etc/javavms_conf file.